# Redirect users from non-certified (non-www) domain to certified (www)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

My client purchased a SSL certificate but only for the www domain.
I'm now trying to set up the redirect rules via .htaccess to redirect visitors from https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com (following [this link](http://www.a2hosting.com/kb/security/ssl/using-www-and-non-www-domains-with-an-ssl-certificate)), but it's not working.
I'm still seeing the certificate error screen and once I agree with the error, I am then redirected to the https version of the website.
Can't this "error" screen be bypassed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **not** avoid the certificate exception. The reason is, even before the request is sent (which includes the `Host: domain.com` header), the SSL handshake must be completed. It is during this handshake that the browser realizes that the certificate says the domain is "www.domain.com" while the domain the user tried to go to is "domain.com", and throws the exception.

No request ever gets sent to the server unless the exception is allowed. Your client needs to buy a cert for both www and non-www. Or make sure all links everywhere include the www.